# Redirect URL not going to show page capybara factorygirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tdd, cucumber, factory-bot, bdd

I'm trying to test the confirmation page after a user clicks register on the form. In development, when a user registers they are redirected to a confirmation page such as `/entrants/(some number)/confirm`. However when I run the test it doesn't hit that page. it only hits `/entrants`. I tried using using `visit` capybara syntax with no success.

sign_in_steps.rb

```
Given(/^there is a entrant sign in page$/) do
  @campaign = create(:campaign)
  @entrant = create(:entrant, campaign: @campaign) 
  @entry = create(:entry, campaign: @campaign, entrant: @entrant)
end

Then(/^I should see confirmation login when I click the register button$/) do
  within '#entrant_create' do
    fill_in('entrant_first_name', with: @entrant.first_name)
    fill_in('entrant_last_name', with: @entrant.last_name)
    fill_in('entrant_email', with: @entrant.email)
    fill_in('entrant_password', with: @entrant.password)
    fill_in('entrant_password_confirmation', with: @entrant.password)
    fill_in('entrant_dob', with: @entrant.dob)
  end
  click_button('REGISTER')
  expect(current_path).to eq "/entrants/#{@entrant.id}/confirm"
end
```

After running cucumber feature

```
expected: "/entrants/1/confirm"
           got: "/entrants"
```

entrant.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :entrant do
    first_name 'John'
    last_name 'Smith'
    email "test@msn.com"
    dob Time.now - 60.years
    password 'password'
  end
end
```

entrant controller

```
def confirm
    @entrant = Entrant.find params[:id]
    set_confirmation_message
end

def set_confirmation_message
  if @entrant.entries.present?
   @title = "Complete Your Contest Entry"
   @message = 'Thank you for your entry! To complete submission, please check your email and click the confirmation link.'
  else
   @message = "To be allowed to enter this contest, please check your email and click the confirmation link."
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your controller say?

Comment: Issue was that email was already added to database when entrant gets created by FactoryGirl. So giving another email will pass through the registration part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with the after register is being clicked. It's because when entrant creates an email address to database, when capybara fills in the email, it sees that it's already taken. So I just fill it in manually with another email address.

```
fill_in('entrant_email', with: 'test@example.com')
```

Comment: In order to make this answer helpful for future visitors, please add some context to explain it, and then mark it as accepted. Alternatively, if you feel that future visitors will not be helped by this, you can delete your answer and question.